# Is there a string to 32 bit integer coding system in elisp?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

Is there a coding system such that `(encode-coding-string msg '??? t)` would convert my message into a list of 32 bit integers?

The `binary` coding system converts well the message to 8 bit data, and I am aware that I could post-process it to convert the result into 32 bits. I'm just wondering if there is already a coding system that does this... :) #lazy

Comment: The Emacs gods answer here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, attempt number two.

I wrote a test generator snippet in python:

```
def make_test_2():
    with open('test2.bin', 'wb') as f:
        args = [1867, 1982]
        
        for a in args:
            f.write((a).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little'))
```

This is a pretty hacky (a couple of `reverse` calls etc).  But, its only meant to be a quick and dirty prototype.

```
(defun read-int-list2 (filename)
  (let ((result '())
        (accumulator '())
        (accum-count 0)
        (accum-max 4))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
      (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'binary) ;; find a way to set temporarily? not sure
      (insert-file-contents-literally filename)
      (while (< (point) (point-max))

        (if (< accum-count accum-max)
            (progn
              (setq accumulator (cons (aref (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (1+ (point))) 0) accumulator))
              (setq accum-count (1+ accum-count))))

        (if (>= accum-count accum-max) ;; four bytes accumulated, lets bundle
            (progn
              (let* ((s (reverse accumulator))
                     (e1 (elt s 0))
                     (e2 (elt s 1))
                     (e3 (elt s 2))
                     (e4 (elt s 3))
                     (val (logior (lsh e4 24) (lsh e3 16) (lsh e2 8) e1))) ;; assume little endian (intel, ARM)
                ;; (message (format "%x %x %x %x -> %d" e1 e2 e3 e4 val))
                (setq result (cons val result))
                (setq accum-count 0)
                (setq accumulator '()))))

        (forward-char)))

    (reverse result)))

(read-int-list2 "test2.bin") ;; (1867 1982)
```

I only did the one test.  So that needs improvement.  In words:

1. accumulate 8 byte chars from the special temp buffer (special because binary/literal load)
2. once the bytes per integer count has been reached, merge the accumulated bytes into an integer by bit shifting (be aware some machines are big endian, I assume here little endian) the bytes into place.
3. dump merged into result list
4. reset the accumulator
5. go to step 1

i have no doubt there are many improvements, my lisp is rusty.

Comment: There is already string-to-list that does what your snippet suggest, but it won't take into account the size of complex characters. I'm looking for something like string-to-unibyte that would do be called string-to-word kind of...

Comment: ah, I see.  Is it just handling utf-8 chars?  Can you give a couple of test strings?  I am not clear on what "complex characters" means.  ideally two or three short hand made "given this input X, this is the desired output Y" etc

Comment: Well I want to convert the binary data of a file into a list of 32 bit integers (I'm working on an md5 implementation for fun: https://github.com/sthilaid/md5.el). By complex characters, I meant multibyte characters. When reading a binary file in emacs, emacs will combine what it think is multibyte characters into a single character (int). In my case, I want to force it to combine all of the text in chunks of 32 bits. Does that make more sense?